# Euler characteristic equation for circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

Firstly what is the Euler characteristic equation and secondly I understand what these regions are but what would the Euler characteristic equations for these regions be and how do we work that out.

Region one is circle with radius square root 5 and region two is the region more than circle of radius 1 and less than radius of circle of square root 5. But I don't know how to proceed ahead from this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the Euler Characteristic? I ask because there are a lot of equivalent ways of finding the Euler Characteristic, and I want to tell answer your question in the most familiar way possible.

Comment: i wonder if approximating the circle with a regular $n$-gon will work...